What should be distance (gap) between Pack+ input and GND?
There is a BQ4050 battery management IC and its reference design schematic. In the below image, there is a spark gap symbol I think labeled as E2, E3, and E4 between battery inputs and GND. I want to know how much distance the air gap should be. The reference design file is here BQ4050 Reference Design Schematic from the Texas Instruments TIDA-00982 BMS reference design.


I can't answer your questions but I can make two suggestions: 1) ask this question on TI E2E as the TI engineers will be the first people to answer or at least tell what considerations are taken, or 2) ask someone who has Altium running on their PC open the layout files and measure the dimensions of the ref design's spark gaps (if they are actually spark gaps, of course).

Thank you, I have just posted there.
